# How to get program to stop running once its met the goal - Java

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I am trying to get the program to stop once it has met this condition fully, i run the program around 100,000 times because this is one of a hundred thousands of cases. But I'm not sure exactly how to make the program stop if it has met. I know if its is met it prints out a way i identify this case, but since i am running over 100,000 times the console does not remember all off the cases it has been through.

```
`public static void stop_running(int cube[][]){
    try {
        if(cube[5][0] == 5 && cube[5][2] == 5 && cube[3][8] == 5 && cube[5][1] == 5 && cube[5][3] == 5 && cube[5][5] == 5);

        }
    catch (Exception stop){

        System.out.println("CHECK");
    }`
```

Comment: What is the try-catch for?

Answer (score 0):

Simply return.

```
public static void stop_running(int cube[][]){
try {
    if(cube[5][0] == 5 && cube[5][2] == 5 && cube[3][8] == 5 && cube[5][1] == 5 && cube[5][3] == 5 && cube[5][5] == 5) {
        return; 
     }
 }
catch (Exception stop){

    System.out.println("CHECK");
}`
```

Comment: And the try-catch is probably unnecessary.

Comment: or System.exit(0);

Comment: for some reason java won't let me have the return statement there @markspace

Comment: @ProgrammingCuber what is your IDE / error message telling you? I don't see why you couldn't.

Comment: That's because you have a syntax issue after if statement. You are ending if with a semicolon (you shouldn't). It should be if (conditions) { return; }

Comment: Adding a return statement there doesn't change anything to how the code functions

Comment: oh i was missing a curly brace @MitchWeaver

Comment: i got rid of the ; and opened and closed the curly brace with return; in it @RichardAbraham

Answer (score 0):

My answer is similar to Richard's, but I'm going to assume that you haven't shown us the whole code.  Return a value from `stop_running()` that tells your calling method whether to stop or not.

```
public static void more_code(int cube[][]) {
    while( true ) {
       // big loop
       if( stop_running( cube )) return;
    }
}

public static boolean stop_running(int cube[][]) {
    if(cube[5][0] == 5 && cube[5][2] == 5 && cube[3][8] == 5 && cube[5][1] == 5 && cube[5][3] == 5 && cube[5][5] == 5)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Missing ")" on if statement ?

Answer (score 0):

Returning (as proposed by Richard Abraham) only works if you are within main method. If not, you can call `System.exit(0)`.

Comment: where in the program would i put this? in the stop_running method?

Comment: @ProgrammingCuber Exactly at the place where you detected that the condition for stopping is fulfilled. If this is within stop_running - then yes.

Answer (score 0):

A few things. First of all, if you want to do something like:

```
while (condition == true){
    //do stuff
}
```

Then define a boolean function:

```
public static bool test(int cube[][]){
    return (cube[5][0] == 5 && cube[5][2] == 5 && cube[3][8] == 5 && cube[5][1] == 5 && cube[5][3] == 5 && cube[5][5] == 5);
}
```

You probably don't need try-catch; there is no exception being thrown by checking an array unless you are trying to read values that are beyond its boundaries. Instead, just run some code to confirm that the range you are testing exists in the cube:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    while(test(myCubeInstance)){
        //do stuff
    }

public static bool test(int cube[][]){
    if existsInCube(5, 5){ //if cube has 5 entries in each dimension
        return (cube[5][0] == 5 && cube[5][2] == 5 && cube[3][8] == 5 && cube[5][1] == 5 && cube[5][3] == 5 && cube[5][5] == 5);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public static bool existsInCube(int row, int col){
    return cube.length >= row and cube[0].length >= col;
}
```

It should be relatively simple to rewrite the boolean functions if I've made a bad assumption about what you're doing. It's been a little while since I wrote in java, so feel free to point out any mistakes or errors I've made. I'll correct them.

Answer (score 0):

To make it closer to your code, I'd do this:

```
public static void stop_running(int cube[][]){
    try {
        if(cube[5][0] == 5 && cube[5][2] == 5 && cube[3][8] == 5 && cube[5][1] == 5 && cube[5][3] == 5 && cube[5][5] == 5)

           //I suppose this if is the exit condition, isn't it? 
           throw new Exception("stop");

    } catch (Exception stop){
        System.out.println("CHECK");
        //If you want the program to exit here, then:
        System.exit(0);

    }
}
```

Comment: Look carefully, I've removed the semicolon on the if, so the throw statement is inside the if.